# Two GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS files

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-pubsub

I've had to download a key for a Google's Firebase service and yet another key for the pub/sub. How am I supposed to reference both keys with the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS key word?

Answer (score 2):

Normally you only use one service account that has the required permissions.

Application Default Credentials (ADC) support one and only one service account JSON key file specified by the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`.

When writing code for Google Cloud, the SDK `clients` support specifying a service account as a parameter. In your example, you will need to create SDK clients using the appropriate credentials (service account JSON key file). The Firebase admin client can use one credential and the Pub/Sub client can use the other credential.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having exactly the same issue. I'm trying to run two different Firestore services on one machine. Each service uses a different Firestore project.  As far as I can see, to explicitly authenticate by directly accessing my JSON key file, I need to do something like this:

FirestoreClient client = Use ClientBuilderBase and its property: CredentialsPath
FirestoreDb = FirestoreDb.Create(firestoreProjectId, client);

But as ClientBuilderBase is an abstract class, I'm stumped.  Anyone whose got some sample code that does this for real would be a real help.

Cheers
Keith